# Div following cursor appears not within parent but at bottom of page?

Tags: jquery, css

I have implemented some sliders on a site whereby when hovering over the slider, a drag indicator appears and follows the cursor. Previosuly, this was working correctly however during devleopment it has ceased to work and even by removing areas of code and styling to try and locate the issue, I'm at a dead end.

The drag indicator is supposed to follow the cursor when hovering over either .issue-carousel or .archive-carousel. The drag indicator has a class of either .issue-carousel-drag-indicator or .article-carousel-drag-indicator depending on which slider you are hovering.

I don't think this is a jquery issue as I can see the top and left parameters changing when the cursor moves, and the css also seems to be fine as if I remove the position: absolute element it appears (but does not move). What is particularly odd is that once the hover takes place, it seems to draw some blank space at the bottom of the page where the drag indicator appears, if you scroll quickly this is evident.

Can anybody offer any insight?

[Staging link](http://70b2c5ae.ngrok.io)

```
.archive-carousel {
    cursor: grab;
    .carousel-cell {
        overflow: hidden;
        img {
            height: 400px;
        }
    }
    &:hover {
        ~ .archive-carousel-drag-indicator {
            visibility: visible;
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }
}

.issue-carousel-drag-indicator,
.archive-carousel-drag-indicator {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background-color: $red;
    z-index: 9999;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}





/* Drag indicator follow cursor */
$('.archive-carousel, .archive-carousel-drag-indicator').on({
    mousemove: function(e) {
        $('.archive-carousel-drag-indicator').css({
            left: e.pageX,
            top: e.pageY
        });
    },
    click: function() {
       $('.archive-carousel-drag-indicator').fadeOut(300);
    }
});

$('.issue-carousel, .issue-carousel-drag-indicator').on({
    mousemove: function(e) {
        $('.issue-carousel-drag-indicator').css({
            left: e.pageX,
            top: e.pageY
        });
    },
    click: function() {
       $('.issue-carousel-drag-indicator').fadeOut(300);
    }
});
```